# how to minimal clone repository to be able list branches and checkout single file

Tags: git, bitbucket

im looking for away to do clone as minimal as i can , 
so no source will be downloaded (checkout)
then after i done the "minimal clone"
i need to be able to do :

```
git branch -r
```

to list all repo branches

Then select branch from the list and checkout only 1 file from the selected branch

i really want to avoid downloading and updating all repo source code.
In this example i want to get all the remote branches of "develop"

what i tried to do "minimal clone" is:

```
git clone  --depth 1 --no-checkout https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/foo/project.git
```

but then when i list the branches:

```
 git branch -r
```

im getting :

```
 origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  origin/develop
```

and when i checkout origin/develop im getting all the sources

but it does download me all the repo sources .

im using git version 2.10.2.windows.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize a repo instead of creating it by `git clone`,

```
git init project
cd project
git remote add origin https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/foo/project.git
```

To list all the refs,

```
git ls-remote
```

If branches only,

```
git ls-remote --heads
```

Pick a branch, say `develop`, and fetch its last commit only,

```
git fetch origin develop --depth 1
```

Config `sparse-checkout` to checkout only 1 file, say `path/to/foo.txt`,

```
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo "path/to/foo.txt" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
```

Checkout the only file,

```
git checkout develop
```

Comment: I have problem , when i do :   echo "foo.txt" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
where foo.txt is in the top level its fine but when i do : echo "src/config/profile/foo.xml" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout  
i can't the the file or the directorys created in my local repo

Comment: @user63898 Does `src/config/profile/foo.xml` exist in the repository if all files are checked out?